# importing .less files are compiled into single .css file

Tags: css, less

I am importing several `.less` files into `styles.less` file like following

```
@import "foo1";
@import "foo2";
@import "foo3";
@import "foo4";
```

Now when I compile `styles.less` file it merge all .less files into `styles.css`. This approach is good when I want to deploy it to production but I want to compile all .less files separately
so that I could easily debug in my chrome dev tools in dev environment. How can I compile them in this way?

Comment: Just don't import them but compile them all one by one as you did for the styles.less

Comment: Hmm, indeed the answer is in the question itself: to compile them separately ... just compile them separately (and do not compile `styles.less`). Although it's not clear how this improves debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Compile the .less files separately. Then link all of them on the HTML page.